# PDFBox 2.0: Overcoming dictionary key encoding

Tags: character-encoding, pdfbox

I am extracting text from PDF forms with Apache PDFBox 2.0.1, extracting the details of AcroForm fields. From a radio button field I dig up the appearance dictionary. I'm interested in the /N and /D entries (normal and "down" appearance). Like this (interactive Bean shell):

```
field = form.getField(fieldName);
widgets = field.getWidgets();
print("Field Name: " + field.getPartialName() + " (" + widgets.size() + ")");
for (annot : widgets) {
  ap = annot.getAppearance();
  keys = ap.getCOSObject().getDictionaryObject("N").keySet();
  keyList = new ArrayList(keys.size());
  for (cosKey : keys) {keyList.add(cosKey.getName());}
  print(String.join("|", keyList));
}
```

The output is

```
Field Name: Krematorier (6)
Off|Skogskrem
Off|R�cksta
Off|Silverdal
Off|Stork�llan
Off|St Botvid
Nyn�shamn|Off
```

The question mark blotches should be Swedish characters "ä" or "å". Using iText RUPS I can see that the dictionary keys are encoded with ISO-8859-1 while PDFBox assumes they are Unicode, I guess.

Is there any way of decoding the keys using ISO-8859-1? Or any other way to retrieve the keys correctly?

This sample PDF form can be downloaded here: http://www.stockholm.se/PageFiles/85478/KYF%20211%20Best%C3%A4llning%202014.pdf

Comment: would you have a sample file to take a look at?

Comment: *The document as a whole was loaded from the file system using UTF-8 encoding.* - A PDF is a binary file. When you load it from the file system, therefore, there should not be any mentioning of any encoding, it should be a binary loading. If some encoding was applied while loading the PDF, it quite likely damages the PDF data.

Comment: @mkl Correct, thanks. (Guess I'll remove that misleading remark.)

Comment: @Maruan Sahyoun Link added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Using iText RUPS I can see that the dictionary keys are encoded with ISO-8859-1 while PDFBox assumes they are Unicode, I guess.
>
> Is there any way of decoding the keys using ISO-8859-1? Or any other way to retrieve the keys correctly?

### Changing the assumed encoding

PDFBox' interpretation of the encoding of bytes in names (only names can be used as dictionary keys in PDFs) takes place in `BaseParser.parseCOSName()` when reading the name from the source PDF:

```
/**
 * This will parse a PDF name from the stream.
 *
 * @return The parsed PDF name.
 * @throws IOException If there is an error reading from the stream.
 */
protected COSName parseCOSName() throws IOException
{
    readExpectedChar('/');
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int c = seqSource.read();
    while (c != -1)
    {
        int ch = c;
        if (ch == '#')
        {
            int ch1 = seqSource.read();
            int ch2 = seqSource.read();
            if (isHexDigit((char)ch1) && isHexDigit((char)ch2))
            {
                String hex = "" + (char)ch1 + (char)ch2;
                try
                {
                    buffer.write(Integer.parseInt(hex, 16));
                }
                catch (NumberFormatException e)
                {
                    throw new IOException("Error: expected hex digit, actual='" + hex + "'", e);
                }
                c = seqSource.read();
            }
            else
            {
                // check for premature EOF
                if (ch2 == -1 || ch1 == -1)
                {
                    LOG.error("Premature EOF in BaseParser#parseCOSName");
                    c = -1;
                    break;
                }
                seqSource.unread(ch2);
                c = ch1;
                buffer.write(ch);
            }
        }
        else if (isEndOfName(ch))
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            buffer.write(ch);
            c = seqSource.read();
        }
    }
    if (c != -1)
    {
        seqSource.unread(c);
    }
    String string = new String(buffer.toByteArray(), Charsets.UTF_8);
    return COSName.getPDFName(string);
}
```

As you can see, after reading the name bytes and interpreting the # escape sequences, PDFBox unconditionally interprets the resulting bytes as UTF-8 encoded. To change this, therefore, you have to patch this PDFBox class and replace the charset named at the bottom.

### Is PDFBox correct here?

According to the specification,  when treating a name object as text

> the sequence of bytes (after expansion of NUMBER SIGN sequences, if any) should be interpreted according to UTF-8, a variable-length byte-encoded representation of Unicode in which the printable ASCII characters have the same representations as in ASCII.

*(section 7.3.5 Name Objects, [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf))*

`BaseParser.parseCOSName()` implements just that.

PDFBox' implementation is not completely correct, though, as already the act of interpreting the name as string without need is wrong:

> name objects shall be treated as atomic within a PDF file. Ordinarily, the bytes making up the name are never treated as text to be presented to a human user or to an application external to a conforming reader. However, occasionally the need arises to treat a name object as text

Thus, PDF libraries should handle names as byte arrays as long as possible and only find a string representation when it is explicitly required, and only then the recommendation above (to assume UTF-8) should play a role. The specification even indicates where this may cause trouble:

> PDF does not prescribe what UTF-8 sequence to choose for representing any given piece of externally specified text as a name object. In some cases, multiple UTF-8 sequences may represent the same logical text. Name objects defined by different sequences of bytes constitute distinct name objects in PDF, even though the UTF-8 sequences may have identical external interpretations.

Another situation becomes apparent in the document at hand, if the sequence of bytes constitutes no valid UTF-8, it still is a valid name. But such names are *changed* by the method above, any unparsable byte or subsequence is replaced by the Unicode Replacement Character '�'. Thus, different names may collapse into a single one.

Another issue is that when writing back a PDF, PDFBox is *not* acting symmetrically but instead interprets the `String` representation of the name (which has been retrieved as a UTF-8 interpretation if read from a PDF) using pure `US_ASCII`, cf. `COSName.writePDF(OutputStream)`:

```
public void writePDF(OutputStream output) throws IOException
{
    output.write('/');
    byte[] bytes = getName().getBytes(Charsets.US_ASCII);
    for (byte b : bytes)
    {
        int current = (b + 256) % 256;

        // be more restrictive than the PDF spec, "Name Objects", see PDFBOX-2073
        if (current >= 'A' && current <= 'Z' ||
                current >= 'a' && current <= 'z' ||
                current >= '0' && current <= '9' ||
                current == '+' ||
                current == '-' ||
                current == '_' ||
                current == '@' ||
                current == '*' ||
                current == '$' ||
                current == ';' ||
                current == '.')
        {
            output.write(current);
        }
        else
        {
            output.write('#');
            output.write(String.format("%02X", current).getBytes(Charsets.US_ASCII));
        }
    }
}
```

Thus, any interesting Unicode character is replaced with the US_ASCII default replacement character which I assume to be '?'.

So it is quite fortunate that PDF names most often do merely contain ASCII characters... ;)

### Historically

According to the implementation notes from the PDF 1.4 reference,

> In Acrobat 4.0 and earlier versions, a name object being treated as text will typically be interpreted in a host platform encoding, which depends on the operating system and the local language. For Asian languages, this encoding may be something like Shift-JIS or Big Five. Consequently, it will be necessary to distinguish between names encoded this way and ones encoded as UTF-8. Fortunately, UTF-8 encoding is very stylized and its use can usually be recognized. A name that is found not to conform to UTF-8 encoding rules can instead be interpreted according to host platform encoding.

Thus, the sample document at hand seems to follow conventions from Acrobat 4, i.e. from the last century.

<sub>Source code excerpts are from PDFBox 2.0.0 but at first glance do not seem to have been changed in 2.0.1 or the development trunk.</sub>

Comment: this is a very good analysis. I've opened https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3347 for that.

Comment: A very complete analysis covering theory and practice. Let me mention that I had no preconceived notions about dictionary key encoding. I stumbled on this sample and noted that some keys contain characters that may be interpreted as ISO-8859-1 escape sequences.

Comment: This document is part of a survey of PDF forms used by several Swedish municipalities. Forms are rarely hand made. Tools impose their conventions on the resulting forms.

Comment: As far as I could see the sample document has been created using MS Word 2007. While this software indeed is old, it is interesting to see that it follows conventions which had been deprecated long ago when it was published ...