# Manipulating acrofields with pdfbox changes encoding of checkboxes onValue

Tags: java, pdfbox

I do some acrofield manipulation for text fields which have parent fields. This works so far, but the form also contains some checkboxes, the will not be changed. But when I store the manipulated pdf to disk and inspect the value of the checkbox, i can see that the value of cb_a.0 has been changed from ÄÖÜ?ß to ?????

My further processing fails because of this unintended change, any idea how to prevent that?

[image]

My testcase

```
@Test
public void changeBoxedFieldsToOne() throws IOException {

    File encodingPdfFile = new File(classLoader.getResource("./prefill/TestFormEncoding.pdf").getFile());
    byte[] encodingPdfByte = Files.readAllBytes(encodingPdfFile.toPath());

    PdfAcrofieldManipulator pdfMani = new PdfAcrofieldManipulator(encodingPdfByte);
    assertTrue(pdfMani.getTextFieldsWithMoreThan2Children().size() > 0);
    pdfMani.changeBoxedFieldsToOne();
    byte[] changedPdf = pdfMani.savePdf();
    Files.write(Paths.get("./build/changeBoxedFieldsToOne.pdf"), changedPdf);

    pdfMani = new PdfAcrofieldManipulator(changedPdf);
    assertTrue(pdfMani.getTextFieldsWithMoreThan2Children().size() == 0);

}

public void changeBoxedFieldsToOne() {
    PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();

    List<PDNonTerminalField> textFieldWithMoreThan2Childrens = getTextFieldsWithMoreThan2Children();

    for (PDField field : textFieldWithMoreThan2Childrens) {
            int amountOfChilds = ((PDNonTerminalField) field).getChildren().size();
            String currentFieldName = field.getPartialName();
            LOG.info("merging fields of fieldnam {0} to one field", currentFieldName);

            PDField firstChild = getChildWithPartialName((PDNonTerminalField) field, "0");
            if (firstChild == null ) {
                LOG.debug("found field which has a dot but starts not with 0, skipping this field");
                continue;
            }
            PDField lastChild = getChildWithPartialName((PDNonTerminalField) field, Integer.toString(amountOfChilds - 1));
            PDPage pageWhichContainsField = firstChild.getWidgets().get(0).getPage();

            try {
                removeField(pdDocument, currentFieldName);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.error("Error while removing field {0}", currentFieldName, e);
            }
            PDField newField = creatNewField(acroForm, field, firstChild, lastChild, pageWhichContainsField);
            acroForm.getFields().add(newField);
            PDAnnotationWidget newFieldWidget = createWidgetForField(newField, pageWhichContainsField, firstChild, lastChild);
            try {
                pageWhichContainsField.getAnnotations().add(newFieldWidget);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.error("error while adding new field to page");
        }
    }
}

public byte[] savePdf() throws IOException {
    try (final ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        //pdDocument.saveIncremental(out);
        pdDocument.save(out);
        pdDocument.close();
        return out.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

I am using PDFBox 2.0.8

Here is the source PDF:https://ufile.io/gr01f or here https://www.file-upload.net/download-12928052/TestFormEncoding.pdf.html

Here the output: https://ufile.io/k8cr3 or here https://www.file-upload.net/download-12928049/changeBoxedFieldsToOne.pdf.html

Comment: please create some code that stands by itself. For example, `getChildWithPartialName` is missing, and several others. Please reduce your code as much as possible to reproduce the problem you're having, i.e. don't dump some giant code here, try to close down on the problem.

Comment: I've tried to download your files for hours now but your file sharing platform seems not to work.

Comment: I added another link to the files, hopefully this works

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I am not sure where the problem is, thats why i added a lot of functions so that you can see which manipulation will be done. I will test if also happens by just adding a field and then storing it.

Answer (score 1):

This indeed is a bug in PDFBox: PDFBox cannot properly handle PDF Name objects containing bytes with values outside the US_ASCII range (in particular outside the range 0..127, and your umlauts are outside).

---

*The first error* in PDF Name handling is that PDFBox internally represents them as strings after a mixed UTF-8 / CP-1252 decoding strategy. This is wrong, according to the PDF specification *a name object is an atomic symbol uniquely defined by a sequence of any characters (8-bit values) except null (character code 0). [...]*

*Ordinarily, the bytes making up the name are never treated as text to be presented to a human user or to an application external to a PDF processor. However, occasionally the need arises to treat a name object as text, such as one that represents a font name [...], a colourant name in a Separation or DeviceN colour space, or a structure type [...]*

*In such situations, the sequence of bytes making up the name object should be interpreted according to UTF-8, a variable-length byte-encoded representation.*

Thus, it generally does not make sense to treat a name as anything else than a byte sequence. Only names used in certain contexts should be meaningful as UTF-8 encoded strings.

Furthermore, a mixed UTF-8 / CP-1252 decoding strategy, i.e. one that first tries to decode using UTF-8 and in case of failure tries again with CP-1252, can create the same string representation for different name entities, so this can indeed falsify by making unequal names equal.

This is not the problem in your case, though, the names you used can be interpreted.

---

*The second error* is, though, that while serializing the PDF it only properly encodes the characters in the strings representing names which are from US_ASCII, all else are replaced by '?':

```
public void writePDF(OutputStream output) throws IOException
{
    output.write('/');
    byte[] bytes = getName().getBytes(Charsets.US_ASCII);
    for (byte b : bytes)
    {
        [...]
    }
}
```

*(from `org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSName.writePDF(OutputStream)`)*

This is where your checkbox values (which internally are represented by PDF Name objects) get damaged beyond repair...

---

A more simple example to show the problem is this:

```
PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
PDPage page = new PDPage();
document.addPage(page);
document.getDocumentCatalog().getCOSObject().setString(COSName.getPDFName("äöüß"), "äöüß");
document.save(new File(RESULT_FOLDER, "non-ascii-name.pdf"));
document.close();
```

In the result the catalog with the custom entry looks like this:

```
1 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Version /1.4
/Pages 2 0 R
/#3F#3F#3F#3F <E4F6FCDF>
>>
```

In the name key all characters are replaced by '?' in hex encoded form (`#3F`) while in the string value the characters are appropriately encoded.

---

After a bit of searching I stumbled over an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37137341/1729265) on this topic I gave almost two years ago. Back then the PDF Name object bytes were always interpreted as UTF-8 encoded which led to issues in that question.

As a consequence the issue [PDFBOX-3347](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3347) was created. To resolve it the mixed UTF-8 / CP-1252 decoding strategy was introduced. As expressed above, though, I'm not a friend of that strategy.

In that stack overflow answer I also already discussed the problems related to the use of `US_ASCII` during PDF serialization but that aspect has not yet been addressed at all.

Another related issue is [PDFBOX-3519](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3519) but its resolution also was reduced to trying to fix the parsing of PDF Names, ignoring the serialization of it.

Yet another related issue is [PDFBOX-2836](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-2836).

Comment: Thanks, great analysis! So I can only hope that it will be fixed in the next version. Or is there some kind of workaround? Did you create an issue at their jira?

Comment: *"So I can only hope that it will be fixed in the next version."* - I cannot guarantee anything here. It should be trivial to get rid of that US_ASCII restriction by simply using UTF-8 instead; this would fix your issue. The conceptual issue of not transporting the name as `byte[]`, though, might have to be analyzed properly before fixing.

Comment: *"Or is there some kind of workaround?"* - Unfortunately `COSName` is final. Otherwise one could have derived one's own `COSName` variant from it which overrides `writePDF` with a version that uses UTF-8, then derived one's own `PDFParser` variant which overrides `parseCOSName` with a version that returns an instance of one's own `COSName` variant, and then instantiate one's `PDDocument` object using that `PDFParser` variant. With `COSName` being `final`, though, that does not work. Probably Javassist can be used to that effect instead, but I would not want to rely on Javassist in production.

Comment: I've created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4076 . I think it is tricky. @AlPhaba I don't get why this is so important. The "on values" are internal values, why is this needed to add Umlauts there?

Comment: *"I think it is tricky"* - there is a trivial half solution: replace US_ASCII by utf-8 in `writePDF`. A full solution indeed is less trivial: a name should have its main representation as a byte sequence, and only for a few specific contexts a string representation should be created. And a name read from a file and later again written to a file should simply have its representing byte sequence written to the target file, no decoding or encoding inbetween.

Comment: @mkl thank you, I have done the "half solution" for now. To Al Phaba: snapshot available at https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.9-SNAPSHOT/